# como sumar datos de un arreglo dependiendo de una condición dentro del mismo arreglo

Tags: php, array

resulta que tengo un array que traigo desde la base de datos, pero de este debo de los campos **[cantidad]** dependiendo de **[unidadxx]** campo dentro del mismo arreglo, pero hasta el momento no me a sido posible,

***ejemplo***
sumar todos los [unidadxx] donde [cantidad] = MESES
 en este caso seria 15 y así  con dias y semanas respectivamente

Arreglo

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [idcotiza] => 2-19
            [idconcep] => 168
            [unidadxx] => MESES
            [cantidad] => 12.00
            [valoruni] => 100000.00
            [descuent] => 0.00
            [valortot] => 1200000.00
            [subtotal] => 1200000.00
            [conobser] => PRUEBA 02
            [conidxxx] => 168
            [condesxx] => ALOJAMIENTO HOTELES
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [idcotiza] => 2-19
            [idconcep] => 141
            [unidadxx] => MESES
            [cantidad] => 3.00
            [valoruni] => 1010.00
            [descuent] => 0.00
            [valortot] => 3030.00
            [subtotal] => 3030.00
            [conobser] => 
            [conidxxx] => 141
            [condesxx] => ALQUILER BRAZO DIESEL 600
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [idcotiza] => 2-19
            [idconcep] => 144
            [unidadxx] => DIAS
            [cantidad] => 7.00
            [valoruni] => 200.00
            [descuent] => 0.00
            [valortot] => 1400.00
            [subtotal] => 1400.00
            [conobser] => 
            [conidxxx] => 144
            [condesxx] => ALQUILER MANIPULADOR TELESCOPIO THD
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [idcotiza] => 2-19
            [idconcep] => 143
            [unidadxx] => DIAS
            [cantidad] => 6.00
            [valoruni] => 456.00
            [descuent] => 0.00
            [valortot] => 2736.00
            [subtotal] => 2736.00
            [conobser] => 
            [conidxxx] => 143
            [condesxx] => ALQUILER BRAZO DIESEL 450 AJ
        )

    [4] => Array
        (
            [idcotiza] => 2-19
            [idconcep] => 168
            [unidadxx] => SEMANAS
            [cantidad] => 3.00
            [valoruni] => 45.00
            [descuent] => 0.00
            [valortot] => 135.00
            [subtotal] => 135.00
            [conobser] => 
            [conidxxx] => 168
            [condesxx] => ALOJAMIENTO HOTELES
        )

    [5] => Array
        (
            [idcotiza] => 2-19
            [idconcep] => 139
            [unidadxx] => SEMANAS
            [cantidad] => 2.00
            [valoruni] => 66.00
            [descuent] => 0.00
            [valortot] => 132.00
            [subtotal] => 132.00
            [conobser] => 
            [conidxxx] => 139
            [condesxx] => ALQUILER BRAZO ELECTRICO E 45
        )

)
```

Intente con esto

```
        if($aDetail["unidadxx"]=="DIAS"){ $nDays=1;}else{ $nDays=0;};
        if($aDetail["unidadxx"]=="SEMANAS"){ $nWeeks=1;}else{ $nWeeks=0;};
        if($aDetail["unidadxx"]=="MESES"){ $nMonths=1;}else{ $nMonths=0;};
        if($nDays =1){
          $dia += $aDetail["cantidad"] ;
        }
        if($nWeeks =1){
          $semana += $aDetail["cantidad"] ;
        }
        if($nMonths =1){
          $mes += $aDetail["cantidad"] ;
          }
```

pero no me a sido posible, agradezco a quien me pueda ayudar.

aca dejo el SQL, aun que es algo largo.
SELECT 
`qtdetail`.*, `concepts`.* 
FROM 
( SELECT IF(`qtheader`.`tipoterx` = 'PROSPECTO', 
            `qtheader`.`nombrexx`,
            IF(`qtheader`.`tipoterx` = 'CLIENTE', 
               IFNULL(`thirdxxx`.`ternomxx`, ''), '')) AS `ternomxx`,
 IF(`qtheader`.`tipoterx` = 'PROSPECTO',
    `qtheader`.`terdirxx`, 
    IF(`qtheader`.`tipoterx` = 'CLIENTE',
       IFNULL(`thirdxxx`.`terdirxx`, ''), '')) AS `terdirxx`,
 IF(`qtheader`.`tipoterx` = 'PROSPECTO', 'Identificación', IF(`qtheader`.`tipoterx` = 'CLIENTE', 'Nit', '')) AS `identity`, 
 `qtheader`.`regestxx` AS `regestxx`, `qtheader`.`fechaxxx` AS `fechaxxx`, `qtheader`.`observax` AS `observax`, `qtheader`.`impuesto` AS `impuesto`, `qtheader`.`validezx` AS `validezx`, `qtheader`.`idcotiza` AS `idcotiza`, (SELECT `ternomxx` FROM `madrecol_0003`.`_0003102` WHERE `teridxxx` = `qtheader`.`sellerid`) AS `sellnomx`, (SELECT `fdpdesxx` FROM `madrecol_0003`.`_0003120` WHERE `fdpidxxx` = `qtheader`.`formapag`) AS `formapag`, `qtheader`.`teridxxx` AS `teridxxx`, `contacts`.`nombrexx` AS `nombrexx`, `contacts`.`telefono` AS `telefono`, `qtheader`.`incluope` AS `incluope`, `qtheader`.`totaliza` AS `totaliza` FROM `madrecol_0003`.`_0003544` AS `qtheader` LEFT JOIN ( SELECT `teridxxx`, `ternomxx`, `terdirxx` FROM `madrecol_0003`.`_0003102` ) AS `thirdxxx` ON `thirdxxx`.`teridxxx` = `qtheader`.`teridxxx` LEFT JOIN ( SELECT `nombrexx`, `telefono`, `idcotiza` FROM `madrecol_0003`.`_0003547` WHERE `secidxxx` = ( SELECT MIN(`secidxxx`) FROM `madrecol_0003`.`_0003547` ) ) AS `contacts` ON `contacts`.`idcotiza` = `qtheader`.`idcotiza` WHERE `qtheader`.`idcotiza` = '2-19' ) AS `qtheader` LEFT JOIN ( SELECT `idcotiza`, `idconcep`, `unidadxx`, `cantidad`, `valoruni`, `descuent`, `valortot`, `subtotal`, `conobser` FROM `madrecol_0003`.`_0003545` ) AS `qtdetail` ON `qtdetail`.`idcotiza` = `qtheader`.`idcotiza` LEFT JOIN ( SELECT `conidxxx`, `condesxx` FROM `madrecol_0003`.`_0003104` ) AS `concepts` ON `concepts`.`conidxxx` = `qtdetail`.`idconcep` WHERE `qtheader`.`regestxx` = 'ACTIVO'

Comment: ¿Te has planteado traer ese dato ya calculado de la base de datos? Si esta opción te parece mejor, modifica la pregunta añadiendo la etiqueta mysql y envíanos el SQL de la base de datos para echarte una mano con la consulta de totales

Comment: @David el sql es algo largo , pero aun así lo agrego a la publicación

Comment: No hace falta que nos envíes todos los registros, con unos pocos para hacer pruebas es suficiente. Muy importantes las tablas, no te dejes ninguna. Veo que en tu consulta ya haces algún total, puedes utilizarla como subconsulta para obtener lo que buscas. Envía todo a ver qué se puede hacer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

La verdad es que con arrays en PHP se resuelve de forma bastante sencilla:

```
$total=0;
foreach($a as $r)
    if($r['unidadxx']=='MESES') $total+=$r['cantidad'];
echo $total;
```

Aunque siga prefiriendo hacerlo directamente en el servidor MySQL con esta consulta:

```
SELECT SUM(cantidad) total FROM subconsulta WHERE unidadxx='MESES';
```

Adjunto el código PHP que genera el array:

```
$a=[
        [
            'idcotiza' => '2-19',
            'idconcep' => '168',
            'unidadxx' => 'MESES',
            'cantidad' => '12.00',
            'valoruni' => '100000.00',
            'descuent' => '0.00',
            'valortot' => '1200000.00',
            'subtotal' => '1200000.00',
            'conobser' => 'PRUEBA 02',
            'conidxxx' => '168',
            'condesxx' => 'ALOJAMIENTO HOTELES',
        ],

        [
            'idcotiza' => '2-19',
            'idconcep' => '141',
            'unidadxx' => 'MESES',
            'cantidad' => '3.00',
            'valoruni' => '1010.00',
            'descuent' => '0.00',
            'valortot' => '3030.00',
            'subtotal' => '3030.00',
            'conobser' => '',
            'conidxxx' => '141',
            'condesxx' => 'ALQUILER BRAZO DIESEL 600',
        ],

        [
            'idcotiza' => '2-19',
            'idconcep' => '144',
            'unidadxx' => 'DIAS',
            'cantidad' => '7.00',
            'valoruni' => '200.00',
            'descuent' => '0.00',
            'valortot' => '1400.00',
            'subtotal' => '1400.00',
            'conobser' => '',
            'conidxxx' => '144',
            'condesxx' => 'ALQUILER MANIPULADOR TELESCOPIO THD',
        ],

        [
            'idcotiza' => '2-19',
            'idconcep' => '143',
            'unidadxx' => 'DIAS',
            'cantidad' => '6.00',
            'valoruni' => '456.00',
            'descuent' => '0.00',
            'valortot' => '2736.00',
            'subtotal' => '2736.00',
            'conobser' => '',
            'conidxxx' => '143',
            'condesxx' => 'ALQUILER BRAZO DIESEL 450 AJ',
        ],

        [
            'idcotiza' => '2-19',
            'idconcep' => '168',
            'unidadxx' => 'SEMANAS',
            'cantidad' => '3.00',
            'valoruni' => '45.00',
            'descuent' => '0.00',
            'valortot' => '135.00',
            'subtotal' => '135.00',
            'conobser' => '',
            'conidxxx' => '168',
            'condesxx' => 'ALOJAMIENTO HOTELES',
        ],

        [
            'idcotiza' => '2-19',
            'idconcep' => '139',
            'unidadxx' => 'SEMANAS',
            'cantidad' => '2.00',
            'valoruni' => '66.00',
            'descuent' => '0.00',
            'valortot' => '132.00',
            'subtotal' => '132.00',
            'conobser' => '',
            'conidxxx' => '139',
            'condesxx' => 'ALQUILER BRAZO ELECTRICO E 45',
        ]

];
```

Comment: gracias por tu ayuda

Comment: Genial, me alegra que te haya resultado útil. Recuerda votar y aceptar la respuesta :) https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Answer (score 2):

Yo haría lo siguiente para este caso:

1. Crear un array (`$mTotals`) con las diferentes claves (distintas) en `unidadxx`. Cada clave tendrá inicialmente el valor `0`
2. Leer el array original (`$mArray`) e ir sumando en `$mTotals` el valor respectivo a `cantidad`

El resultado final será un array de totales que luego puedes portar a otro sitio o bien mostrar allí mismo.

El código sería este:

```
#1
$mTotals= array_fill_keys(array_column($mArray, 'unidadxx'),0);

foreach ($mArray as $item){
     #2
     $mTotals[$item["unidadxx"]]+=$item["cantidad"];   
}
```

---

#### Prueba de resultados:

Si haces un `print_r($mTotales);` verás que tienes un array organizado con los totales de días, semanas y meses:

```
Array
(
    [MESES] => 15
    [DIAS] => 13
    [SEMANAS] => 5
)
```

Y para mostrar los valores por separado:

```
echo $mTotales["DIAS"].PHP_EOL;
echo $mTotales["SEMANAS"].PHP_EOL;
echo $mTotales["MESES"].PHP_EOL;
```

Salida:

```
13
5
15
```

---

### Demostración

Aquí puedes ver una <kbd>**[DEMO EN LÍNEA](https://rextester.com/XERXX77486)**</kbd> y hacer pruebas en un escenario real.

Espero te sea de utilidad, a ti y a esta distinguida comunidad.

Comment: gracias por tu ayuda